# CI Runner - use G++ 4.8 for npm install step

Tags: node.js, centos, g++, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to have CI Runner use G++ 4.8 for npm install step.  I am messing around witht he .gitlab-ci.yml - here is my current version:

```
before_script: 
- . /etc/profile.d/_environment.sh 
- . /etc/profile.d/runner.sh 
- nvm use v5.3.0

build: 
script: 
- scl enable devtoolset-2 bash 
- g++ --version 
- npm install 
- gulp build 
tags: 
- shell

style-analysis: 
script: 
- gulp style 
tags: 
- shell
```

Unforutnately my build is failing. The step "scl enable devtoolset-2 bash" should sweitch to G++ 4.8 and it does when I runner it on the console directly. The next line "g++ --version" is meant to capture the version so I can debug what is happening here. It is not show version 4.8 instead 4.4. Whcih will cause my build to fail. Here is the "head" of the output

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d) 
Using Shell executor... 
Running on hqdevrunner01... 
Fetching changes... 
Removing node_modules/ 
HEAD is now at 082a6fa remove allow failure 
From https://hqdevgit01.services.com/operations/-technical-operations-portal 
082a6fa..9e36ed9 master -> origin/master 
Checking out 9e36ed91 as master... 
Previous HEAD position was 082a6fa... remove allow failure 
HEAD is now at 9e36ed9... g++4.8 and c++ 11 feaures enabled as part of build 
$ . /etc/profile.d/_environment.sh 
$ . /etc/profile.d/runner.sh 
$ nvm use v5.3.0 
Now using node v5.3.0 (npm v3.3.12) 
$ scl enable devtoolset-2 bash 
$ npm install 
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0 
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported 
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.4.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x || 0.11.x"} (current: {"node":"5.3.0","npm":"3.3.12"}) 
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is no longer maintained. See its readme for upgrade details.

> ursa@0.9.1 install /home/gitlab-runner/builds/6acc3401/0/operations/-technical-operations-portal/node_modules/chef-api/node_modules/ursa 
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/6acc3401/0/operations/-technical-operations-portal/node_modules/chef-api/node_modules/ursa/build' 
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o 
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.h:10, 
from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3: 
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:41:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler 
In file included from /home/gitlab-runner/.node-gyp/5.3.0/include/node/node.h:42, 
from ../src/ursaNative.h:9, 
from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
```

It looks as though the value from one step is not carried forward to the next step. For instance - as if they happen in their own shells.

Answer (score 0):

GITLAB is actively working to move this project forward.  At this point, the work in one step is not carried forward to other steps.  I beleive the theory is that each step can be carried our in parallel on different CI Runners.

My solution: MEGA STEP

```
build: 
script: 
- scl enable devtoolset-2 bash 
- g++ --version 
- npm install 
- gulp build 
- gulp style 
tags: 
- shell
```

Its a work arond for now.